# How to display images into RichTextBox from Outlook message file(.MSG)?

Tags: c#

I have an outlook message file , converting into stream using below code

```
Stream messageStream = File.Open(MessageFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Taking this stream into OutlookStorage.Message object as shown below.

```
OutlookStorage.Message message = new OutlookStorage.Message(messageStream);
```

I am displaying this message object body into RichTextBox.

```
RichTextBox1.Rtf = message.BodyRTF;
```

In RichTextBox1 am able to see only Text and formatted data wherin images are not displaying in richtextbox

Instead of images displaying Image names like "Description: cid:image002.png@01CD86A2.E62E9990" .

I have all images as outlook attachments. In message.BodyRTF i can see image  tags as

```
<img width=229 height=262 id="Picture_x0020_2" src="cid:image002.png@01CD86A2.E62E9990"> .
```

I want to display images as it is instead of image names. How can i?
can any have source code for the implementing the same? or any suggestion would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Looks like it is possible: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R

Comment: ofcourse that is possible but my requirement is different from that. I have messages in an outlook message file(had both text and images) , i am able to read the text and display but where as for images i can't. I want to display images also?